# Getting data from Mixpanel API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, mixpanel

I am trying to get data from a Mixpanel API. The JSON result looks like this:

`{"computed_at": "2019-11-19T10:36:33.908802+00:00", "legend_size": 1, "data": {"series": ["2019-11-11", "2019-11-12", "2019-11-13"], "values": {"page views": {"2019-11-12": 111, "2019-11-11": 573, "2019-11-13": 209}}}}`

I want to populate this object with the values:

```
 public class ResultData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Specifically I want `ResultData.Value` to be the sum of `111`, `573` and `209` (the page views over 3 days). Can anyone please help me to work out how to do this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
  public async Task<ResultData> GetData()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var formattedDateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    var formattedDateTo = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    string baseUrl = "https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/segmentation?from_date=" + formattedDateFrom + "&to_date=" + formattedDateTo + "&event=patient+-+booking+-+booked+appointment";

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl);

                    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultData>(stringResult);

                    var mixpanelResult = new ResultData();
                    mixpanelResult.Value = rawData.Value;
                    mixpanelResult.Title = "Page Views";

                    return await Task.FromResult(mixpanelResult);

                } catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
                {
                    // Not sure what to put here but will try and work it out later 
                }

            }
        }
```

I know `rawData.Value` isn't correct as it needs to be the sum of the page views, but at the moment it's not even deserializing. When I add a break point, `rawData` is nothing more than the `baseUrl`

I'm a bit of a newbie at all this and any help would be really appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case your `json` keys are dyanamic, so we can not `deserialize` it based on any class because it will not going to match your json string.

I have tried something with the use of your `json`, where you can get sum of your required keys. may be it is not best solution, but it may help you.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("{\"computed_at\": \"2019-11-19T10:36:33.908802+00:00\", \"legend_size\": 1, \"data\": {\"series\": [\"2019-11-11\", \"2019-11-12\", \"2019-11-13\"], \"values\": {\"page views\": {\"2019-11-12\": 111, \"2019-11-11\": 573, \"2019-11-13\": 209}}}}");

var options = obj["data"]["values"]["page views"].ToList();

var sum = 0;

foreach (var item in options)
{
   sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.FirstOrDefault());
}
```